# Bootstrap 4 navbar always on 2 lines

Tags: bootstrap-4, navbar

I am trying to solve a problem that seems obvious,
I used a standard Bootstrap code, with Bootstrap 4.1 but it does not behave exactly like a want (and like i ve seen it in the documentation)

My goal is to reproduce this (uncollapsed on one line)
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/#nav
[image]

But my navbar ends up on 2 lines as soon as it is uncollapsed, see here:

[image]
see it here on jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/acourdavault/3jnfgk5z/1/#&togetherjs=D7vbBSPwLI

Code here:

```
    <html>

<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <!-- Image and text -->
        <nav class="navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light sticky-top">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                Brand
            </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup"
                aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
                <div class="navbar-nav">
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home
                        <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Notifications</a>
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Settings</a>
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Help</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div id="container">
    </div>
    <footer></footer>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

## Workaround

I can get it to work if instead of having

`nav:
  - nav-brand
  - toggler
  - navbar-collapse:
    - navbar-nav`

I do

`nav:
  - toggler
  - navbar-collapse:
    - nav-brand
    - navbar-nav`

**but that s not what the doc from boot strap says**
Also the toggler is still not aligned on the right which it should by default

Answer (score 0):

FYI,

the error is that it s missing the main "navbar" class in the tag ,

100% my fault, no comment.